# How to know how many bounds an inequality has?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can you know, **before solving it**, how many bounds an inequality should have? For example $$ \dfrac{x^2 + 2}{1-x^2} < 3$$

A priori to me it looks like it would have 2 bounds because it's a quadratic, but the solutions are actually $$x>1, x<-1,   -\dfrac{1}{2} < x < \dfrac{1}{2}$$

If I hadn't know that I should have been looking for 4 bounds , I would have just stopped after obtaining 2.

Another example $$ -1 < -\dfrac{1}{x} + 2x <1 $$

This has the solutions $$ -1 < x < -\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2} < x < 1$$

How could I see how many bounds I should get? Perhaps not an exact number, but just so I can know when I have a complete answer.

Comment: Any inequality has intervals describing many infinitely solutions. How can it be enumerated?

Comment: @BabakS You know what I mean. I gave 2 examples. I'm not sure how they're called, perhaps bounds or something.

Comment: @BabakS. I edited it. I still don't know whether bounds is correct or not, but I'm hoping the question is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to rational inequalities of the form $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, then the number of bounds will be the number of real roots of the numerator and the denominator, treating multiple roots as a single root, including holes.

In your case,
\begin{align*}\frac{x^{2} + 2}{1 - x^{2}} &< 3 \\ \frac{x^{2} + 2}{1 - x^{2}} - 3 &< 0 \\ \frac{x^{2} + 2 + 3x^{2} - 3}{1 - x^{2}} &< 0 \\ \frac{4x^{2} - 1}{1 - x^{2}} &< 0 \end{align*}

Then, you can see that $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ are vertical asymptotes and $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x = -\frac{1}{2}$ are the roots. Therefore, you have four bounds.

For absolute value inequalities, it is quite complicated for me at the moment, I'll just leave it to you.